# VBA & teams: is it possible to open Excel files in teams via a macro from another workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, microsoft-teams

I maintain files for tracking certain items, their workflow statuses and other data related to an entry/item.

The files all use macros and activex buttons for arguably fast(er) navigation and automated data processing. Because these are 9 files, I use a main "admin" workbook, for the lack of a better term, to keep them all updated in regards to their content, formatting and macros.

There are a few noteworthy aspects to mention:

- Multiple colleagues work with these files.
- They files currently are located on a network drive. Hence it is arguably easy to access these files, since it is quite easy to either use a defined path (as a string variable) or have the colleague navigate to the files' folder by using [Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.application.filedialog).
- The company bought/is in the Office 365 program, so we all have access to Teams, Sharepoint and Outlook and so forth.

So. If the discussion comes up to put files in teams, could I mention that it is possible to open these Excel files in teams through a macro from a workbook?

The user/or "admin" would have Teams running already.

If yes, an additional bonus would be the ability to check if the file is checked out in teams.

Comment: Unlikely. It would be behind a Microsoft login possibly with an encryption key. Have a look at the share url for the file in teams. Likely in sharepoint, shared files, under directory for that channel/directory. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/file-storage-in-teams-df5cc0a5-d1bb-414c-8870-46c6eb76686a#:~:text=Files%20that%20you%20share%20in,the%20people%20in%20that%20conversation.

Comment: Thank your for your reply. Hm, ok. :( Well, of course teams would be running already when I start that macro (the one which should access the files in teams). Does that play a role or not? Also, I amended the op with details around Office 365.

Answer (score 2):

files in Teams are stored in the SharePoint Online behind the Team. Though you might also access the file in the cloud directly, a very easy way could be to [Sync](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sync-sharepoint-and-teams-files-with-your-computer-6de9ede8-5b6e-4503-80b2-6190f3354a88) the files locally and access them from the Sync location. Let the Sync engine then synchronize your changes for you.